# Iterate through dataframe to find first row that satisfies condition for each group of id

Tags: python, pandas

I have panel data with id, time. For each id, after start =1 , I want to identify the first time that satisfy the rule: having "number in" greater than previous "number out".

With the example data below, the expected result is: for id=1, time =5; and for id=2 , time =3. The explanation is as below.

For id = 1, start =1 occurs a time =1. Tracking from time =1, time=5 is what I need as it is the first having "number in" = 4 and it is higher than prior "number out" = 1 occurs in time =3 (after start=1).

Similarly, for id=2, time=3 is what satisfy the rule

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'time': [1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4],
                   'start':[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                   'number out': [2,99,1,13,9,10,2,8,8],
                   'number in': [2,9,1,0,4,1,5,7,8]})
df
```

```
   id  time  start  number out  number in
0   1     1      1           2          2
1   1     2      0          99          9
2   1     3      0           1          1
3   1     4      0          13          0
4   1     5      0           9          4
5   2     1      1          10          1
6   2     2      0           2          5
7   2     3      0           8          7
8   2     4      0           8          8
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please show expected output?

Comment: So what's your question? If you're looking for help doing this, what do you need help with exactly? To start, are you aware of `df.groupby`? Check out [ask].

Comment: What do you mean by prior "number out"?

Comment: Is it the first number out after start?

Comment: @keramat: prior "number out" is any "number out" occurs after start=1. and it is not necessary the first after start=1

Comment: So you want the first number in which is greater than an prior "number out"?

Comment: not clear with id2. If time=3, then number in=7, then the previous number out=10 is greater than 7.

Comment: @ inquirer, for id2,  time =3 is the first time number_in (=7) greater than previous number out (which occurs at time=2 at value out = 2)

Comment: @HnV did you get what you wanted?

Answer (score 1):

The data is grouped by id. Apply is applied to them with a custom function. The first index after start=1(ind) is obtained. ind_in is the index at which to start searching for number in.

A check is used if there is no data so that an error does not occur. If you are sure of your data, you can remove this line:

```
if ind_in[0] > 0 and ind_in[0] <= x.index[-1]:
```

Next, in the 'aaa' list generator, each 'number in' element is compared to an array. If at least one element matches the condition, a boolean mask is stored. It is used for sampling as an index.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                   'time': [1,2,3,4,5, 1,2,3,4],
                   'start':[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],
                   'number out': [2,99,1,13,9,10,2,8,8],
                   'number in': [2,9,1,0,4,1,5,7,8]})

print(df)
def my_func(x):
    ind = x[x['start'] == 1].index + 1
    ind_in = ind + 1

    if ind_in[0] > 0 and ind_in[0] <= x.index[-1]:
        number_out = x.loc[ind[0]:x.index[-2], 'number out']
        aaa = [i for i in range(ind_in[0], x.index[-1] + 1)
               if (x.loc[i, 'number in'] > number_out.values).any()]

        return x.loc[aaa[0], 'time']



print(df.groupby('id').apply(my_func))
```

Output

```
id
1    5
2    3
dtype: int64
```